# Why does using different units yield different areas?

Tags: geometry, area, unit-of-measure

this question has been bugging me for a while now! I was drawing boxes over some squares in a book and then wrote 1cm and 10mm for the line length, and when I calculated the area I realised that the areas were not the same but they occupied the same amount of space.

Am I missing something obvious or is there an explanation?

Attached is a diagram of what I mean. All squares of the same dimensions for mm, cm and m.

[image: The diagram]

Comment: You appear to have a basic misunderstanding about units measuring area. There are 100 square mm in 1 square cm, and 10000 square cm in one square m. It's a little telling that you're still labeling area with the unit of length, because that is a conceptual problem.

Comment: The area unit is the square of the length unit. So $100 mm^2$ is $1 cm^2$ not 10.

Comment: So does that mean 100cm^2 is the same as 1m^2? If so, what is 1cm^2 in m^2?

Comment: @Samuelf80 No, it specifically does _not_ mean that $100cm^2$ is $1m^2$. You can show this by making a drawing like you have up there, but with side length $1m$ and with $1cm\times 1cm$ tiles. How many tiles do you need to cover the square? You need $100$ of them just for one row, so...?

Comment: Right. So if as a decimeter (10cm) would 100cm^2 be 1dm^2? And your answer would it be 10000cm^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't made a mistake, and the areas are equal. It's just that $100mm^2 = 1cm^2 = 0.0001m^2$ is the actual relation between the different area units. What you have done here is a correct proof of that fact.

Comment: Wow I never knew that! So if a square is 1mm^2 does that mean its 0.0001m^2?

Comment: No, you don't have enough zeroes after the decimal point. Add another two to get $1mm^2 = 0.000001m^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If length is measured in millimeters ($\textrm{mm}$), then area is measured in square millimeters ($\textrm{mm}^2$).

If length is measured in centimeters ($\textrm{cm}$), then area is measured in square centimeters ($\textrm{cm}^2$).

One square centimeter ($1 \textrm{ cm}^2$) is 100 square millimeters ($100 \textrm{ mm}^2$).

And similarly where the unit is meters.

I think you are confused because you have used linear units instead of areal units when you wrote down the area. You computed it correctly, just didn't write the correct units for the numerical answers.